# React.js/React-Native how to skip Map() iteration if condition is falsy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this simple component in React-Native, My goal is to skip the iteration if the given argument **gradeIsMandatory** is false, it should only iterate over **warranty** and **price**,
How can I achieve this result without affecting performance? I will take any advice thanks

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, SectionList, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';





export const ModalHeader: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const gradeIsMandatory = false
    
    //code I tried to use
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!gradeIsMandatory){
            let appendGrade =  { key: 'grade', title: 'Grade' }
            modalTabs.push(appendGrade)
        }
    },[])
    return (
        <View>
            <View>
                <View>
                    {modalTabs.map((tab, i) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                          <Text>{tab.title}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))}
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const modalTabs = [
    { key: 'warranty', title: 'Your Waranty' },
    { key: 'price', title: 'Your price' }
]
```

Comment: If you need to skip, you're looking for `filter`, not `map`.

Comment: They're also useful in conjunction - `items.filter(shouldIKeep).map(renderJSX)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a conditional append.

```
const extendedTabs = [...modalTabs, ...(gradeIsMandatory ? [{ key: 'grade', title: 'Grade' }] : [] )];
```

Answer (score 0):

this useEffect will run once just after the first render of the component, manipulating modalTabs there will do nothing becuase modalTabs is not a State of this component. the correct way is:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const modalTabsInitialValue = [
  { key: "warranty", title: "Your Waranty" },
  { key: "price", title: "Your price" }
];

export default (props) => {
  const [modalTabs, setModalTabs] = useState(modalTabsInitialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.gradeIsMandatory) {
      setModalTabs((prevModalTabs) => {
        const appendGrade = { key: "grade", title: "Grade" };
        return [...prevModalTabs, appendGrade];
      });
    }
  }, [props.gradeIsMandatory, setModalTabs]);

  return {
    ...
  }
};
```

1. send the gradeIsMandatory as a property to this component
2. define modalTabs as state
3. use a useEffect hook with props.gradeIsMandatory as a dependency
4. inside the useEffect based on the value of gradeIsMandatory create a new array and change the modalTabs state forcing the component to reRender

**Update:** this is not the best solution for this problem, the correct answer as windowsill said is a simple const: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038438/react-js-react-native-how-to-skip-map-iteration-if-condition-is-falsy/71038626#71038626)

Comment: This definitely works, but it's the derived state anti-pattern. Because the wanted output is deterministic, ie the result is always the same based on given inputs, a simple `const` statement is all you need. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: I agree with you, in this case which the result is deterministic using a simple const at the top of the functional component is absolutely correct, my answer causes an extra render, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would delete the useEffect and render this:

```
return (
    <View>
        <View>
            <View>
                {modalTabs.map((tab, i) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                      <Text>{tab.title}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ))}
                {
                  gradeIsMandatory && <TouchableOpacity><Text>Grade</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                }
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot skip a map iteration. You can however just return `<Fragment />` if your map condition isn't met.